# Ionic and firebase connexion system

Tags: javascript, facebook, ionic-framework, firebase

I am creating a application for my school in France, and I have a problem with firebase on my Ionic app. I try to create a user system, with login, signin, signup and maybe Facebook connexion.

I don't understand, I add this on my header section :

```
<script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
```

but it's doesn't work. This is my script :

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.loginEmail = function(){
    var ref = new Firebase("https://WizzU.firebaseio.com");
    ref.authWithPassword({
      email    : $scope.data.email,
      password : $scope.data.password
    }, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
      }
    });

  };
})
// Inscription Controller
.controller('signinCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.signupEmail = function(){  
  var ref = new Firebase("https://WizzU.firebaseio.com");
  ref.createUser({
    email    : $scope.data.email,
    password : $scope.data.password
  }, function(error, userData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
    }
  });
};
});
```

And I add firebase in my modules in app.js :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'firebase'])
```

I have this message :

```
ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined
```

Does anyone could help me ? I'm totally lost !
Thank you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631597/firebase-not-defined-super-fixable-but-fix-is-not-working-hello-world-example

Comment: Is the same error, it has to do with the firebase version update

Comment: Ok ! thank you, but I try with the new version of firebase, and I have this error now : ReferenceError: email is not defined

Comment: which part of the code? the create user?

Comment: Yes, i try to create a email/password connexion and I follow the instructions here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account

Comment: But there is this error

Comment: are you still putting the email:  and the password:?

Comment: I'm not sur to understand, do you meen this : email    : $scope.data.email,
      password : $scope.data.password ?

Comment: yes i thin the "email:" is creating the email is not defined

Comment: this is my code now for sign up :.controller('signinCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.signupEmail = function(){  
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
    };
});

Comment: where are the email and password vars defined?

Comment: They are not defined, where have I to create theme ? I had to put $scope.data.email and $scope.data.password ?

Comment: But where I had to put theme ?